# What are the WordPress alternatives for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, content-management-system

What are the WordPress alternatives for Ruby on Rails? How do they compare to WordPress?

Answer (score 27):

[Refinery](http://refinerycms.com/) looks really simple but I don't have an in depth comparison to WordPress.  Looks like it has a lot less features but likely easier to maintain and extend upon.  It's pretty standard to write really crappy code in the WordPress community.

Answer (score 15):

I've been using WordPress <strike>more or less against my will</strike> for about <strike>two</strike> four years now (<strike>since I started using other frameworks</strike> (I've started to really love WP again)). I think there is no "good Rails alternative". Of course there are a lot of blog engines but none have as many plugins available or are as well known with clients. Let's be honest, WP has a fantastic front-end, clients seem to like that. The reason "we developers" look for Rails alternatives is obviously because Rails developer aren't comfortable with WP. But there's no platform out there that has the same out-of-the-box completeness and user friendliness as WP. For blog-like purposes that is of course.

Comment: Wordpress indeed does come with a lot of out of the box very useful features. However, what do you do on Wordpress when you need to update thousands of posts? In the ruby community there are very powerful tools such as sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), which allows you to process thousands of background jobs, allowing whatever app one is building to scale. Wordpress does not have a background job processing platform that is any where near the sophistication of sidekiq. Last time I checked I think there was Bernard PHP, but it's underwhelming compared to sidekiq.

Answer (score 9):

[Publify](https://publify.github.io) can be a answer, but I'm not able to compare with WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into [Wordscript](https://github.com/redcap3000/Wordscript) ; it includes API's written in Ruby and PHP that connects to existing WordPress databases and returns json structures (made from generated SQL).

Useful if you want to keep full administrative features of WordPress, and have a somewhat simple WordPress site. Neither version requires WordPress to be installed locally, but you can't really do anything administrative with the api or comments/custom fields (yet). Also the API is much faster and consumes a fraction of the resources WordPress would.